# Ansible: how to pass set of variables to a parameter?

Tags: ansible

say I have a list of vars like that:

```
- role: test-role
       vars:
          host-groups:
           - test-group1
           - test-group2
           - test-group3
```

I need to traverse this list (with loop I guess) and pass each var from it i.e. each group name to the parameter adding the host to listed groups:

```
      groups:
      - default-test-group
      - "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ host-groups }}"
```

I thought it would just iterate the list (host-groups) passing each var from it to the parameter "groups". Apparently it just overwrites the previous iteration and final execution of this parameter includes "default-test-group" and "test-group3".

How should I do this properly?

Comment: its not clear,  when you play a playbook, the tasks are applied on each host defined in the playbook... so in your case, the different vars belongs to each host...i suggest you to show your playbook

Comment: there's not much left in the playbook itself, basically it's a zabbix module play that registers each host in the zabbix server and assigns them the host groups based on what was given in the "host-groups" list passed to the role (along with the default one).

I just don't know how to pass all the group names from list to a parameter that also needs a list of values..

Comment: sorry but i dont understand your problem....maybe show the initial start and the result you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the lists. For example, given the lists

```yaml
host_groups:
  - test-group1
  - test-group2
  - test-group3
my_groups:
  - default-test-group
```

the task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ my_groups + host_groups }}"
```

gives

```yaml
my_groups:
  - default-test-group
  - test-group1
  - test-group2
  - test-group3
```

---

**Notes**

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    host_groups:
      - test-group1
      - test-group2
      - test-group3
    my_groups:
      - default-test-group

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ my_groups + host_groups }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_groups
```

2. *group* is a [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables). You can't change it. For example, use *my_groups* instead.
3. *host-groups* isn't [valid name of a variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). Change the dash, for example, for the underscore *host_groups*.

Comment: Thanks, don't worry about those names, these are just examples.
Basically what I need is to figure out how to parse a variable list to an option in playbook task that needs group names listed as follows:

`
host_groups:
      - default-test-group
      - groupname_parsed_from_list_nr1
      - group_parsed_from_list_nr2
      - group_parsed_from_list_nr3
`